# Prerequisite showing on OS that was not specified

Tags: installshield, prerequisites

I have a Basic MSI Project that has several prereqs. I set the launch conditions for the MSI to be Win Vista SP2, Win 7 SP1, Win 8+ and their corresponding Server OSs. Now, when running the installer on Win XP, the launch condition fails and I get a pop up message. That's great, however I was finding that I had some prereqs that were popping up before that point and would need to be installed before realizing that I can't even install the program on the OS. So, to fix this problem I went through each prereq and set the OSs that the prereq would run under to the same as the launch conditions. This worked for every prereq except one. I can't seem to figure out why this one prereq is still showing up on XP. Listed below is the prereq in question and it's conditions tab contents.

[image: HERE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but for some reason InstallShield was pulling a prerequisite with different conditions during the build. I've checked Tools -> Options-> Prereq tab and it had the correct path there. When I fixed the prereq in another location everything worked fine. So I guess the issue is resolved now.